# AS3: Keep MovieClip on top

Tags: actionscript-3

So this is a little hard to explain, I am going to try my best but please just bear with me.

OK. So I am creating a game that involves a road and cars move across it at a random time (every 5 seconds or so)

I use the below code to create the cars and the direction they shall be travailing
and remove once finished tweening across the screen.

```
 public function animateCars()
    {
        CarMC = Random_Car();

        if (CarLeft)
        {
            CarMC.x = 0;
            CarMC.y = 245;
            CarMC.name = "CarNumber_"+CarNumber;
            addChildAt(CarMC,numChildren - 1);
            MoveCar = new Tween(CarMC,"x",None.easeNone,-60,900,12,true);
            MoveCar.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, CarFinished);
            MoveCar.start();
        }
        else
        {
            CarMC.x = 0;
            CarMC.y = 258;
            CarMC.name = "CarNumber_"+CarNumber;
            CarMC.scaleX *=  -1;
            addChildAt(CarMC,numChildren - 1);
            MoveCar = new Tween(CarMC,"x",None.easeNone,800,-260,12,true);
            MoveCar.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, CarFinished);
            MoveCar.start();
        }
        CarNumber++;
    }

    // Loads another car when finished
    function CarFinished(e:TweenEvent):void
    {
        removeChild(getChildByName("CarNumber_"+CarNumberR));
        CarNumberR++;
    }
```

This all works perfect *(well sorta but this is not the current issue*)*

In this game you can also pick up and place objects. Using the below code:

```
    function addBuilding(Text:String)
    {
        HoldingBuilding = true;
        CursorPointer.visible = false;
        CursorGrab.visible = true;
        Building = new CarWash();
        Building.x = MouseX - MouseX % size;
        Building.y = MouseY - MouseY % size2;
        Building.rotation = 0;
        addChildAt(Building,numChildren);
    }
```

Again this works fine, when you hover the building over the car the car stays under it. (like it should)

The problem's occur when you place the car too near the road, and for the first building it works fine but then if you add a second building the car will go under the newest building and over the oldest building.

and I can't work out how I can keep the placed buildings on top **or the cars on the bottom**

This is the placing code:

```
function DropBuilding(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            if (HoldingBuilding)
            {
                if (BuildingPlacement)
                {
                    HoldingBuilding = false;
                    BuildingPlacement = false;
                    CursorPointer.visible = true;
                    CursorGrab.visible = false;

                    Building.x = MouseX - MouseX % size;
                    Building.y = MouseY - MouseY % size2;
                    Building.rotation = 0;
                    Building.transform.colorTransform = NoColour;
                    Building.removeChild(BuildingBase);
                    BuildingBase = new Sprite();
                    BuildingShaddow = new Sprite();
                    ShakeTimer.stop();
                }
                else
                {
                    ShakeTimer.start();
                }
            }
        }
```

Thank you in advance for anything you can do to help keep either the buildings on top or the cars always on the bottom.

Eli

---

*Just incase you wondered this issue i have with the car tweening currently is every no and again (and i have not worked out why) one or two of the cars will just stop moving for 5 seconds then disappear.

Comment: @bokan Thank you for your comment, I will at some point look into it more. But unless that is the only way to fix my issue i don't see much point in it at the moment.

Comment: Just a note/tip: `addChildAt(Building,numChildren)` is exactly the same as `addChild(Building)`.  addChild always puts the child on top of everything else

Comment: Another tip,  in AS3 - to make code more readable (a very good thing when asking others to troubleshoot it), the defacto standard is to have instances/vars start with a lower-case letter, and Class names start with Upper case letters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every time you generate a car in your `animateCars()` function, you could iterate through all the children and put the buildings above the cars, but that's a little tedious and unnecessary (and not very efficient).

This would be a much better method:

```
//create a container for the cars
var carContainer:Sprite = new Sprite();
addChild(carContainer);

//create a container for the buildings
var buildingContainer:Sprite = new Sprite();
addChild(buildingContainer);
```

Since you added `buildingContainer` after `carContainer`, it will always be on top (including everything you put in it)

So now your `animateCars` method:

```
public function animateCars()
{
    CarMC = Random_Car();
    carContainer.addChild(CarMC);

    if (CarLeft)
    {
        CarMC.x = 0;
        CarMC.y = 245;
        MoveCar = new Tween(CarMC,"x",None.easeNone,-60,900,12,true);
    }
    else
    {
        CarMC.x = 0;
        CarMC.y = 258;
        CarMC.scaleX *=  -1;
        MoveCar = new Tween(CarMC,"x",None.easeNone,800,-260,12,true);
    }


    MoveCar.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, CarFinished);
    MoveCar.start();
}
```

Then your `carFinished` method:

```
function CarFinished(e:TweenEvent):void
{
    carContainer.removeChild((e.currentTarget as Tween).obj as Random_Car);
}
```

Then in your `addBuilding` method, change `addChildAt(Building,numChildren);` to:

```
buildingContainer.addChild(Building);
```

Comment: This works great thanks for explain all this.
only one issue is a get an error when removing the tweens. `TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null.` I have tried  `carContainer.removeChild(getChildByName("CarNumber_"+CarNumberR));` but no fix, do you think you know why there is this issue?

Comment: Look at the CarFinished method I added above and try that. No need for the CarNumber variable,  plus it may be a typo in your comment, but you have `CarNumberR` - note the R at the end - this isn't what your using when you name the car

Comment: @LondonDrugs_MediaServices A great explanation.

Comment: @LondonDrugs_MediaServices I have not been able to get that to work gives me an error:`Implicit coercion of a value of type Function to an unrelated type Class.` **&&** `Implicit coercion of a value with static type Object to a possibly unrelated type flash.display:DisplayObject.`
Also what would be the issue with just removing the `removeChild` function and just leaving the cars when they stop?

Comment: If you don't remove the cars and you keep generating new ones, they'll stay in memory, gradually slowing down your application and potentially crashing it after a long time.

Comment: What line is generating those errors? the `carContainer.removeChild` line?

Comment: @LondonDrugs_MediaServices Yeh they are on that line.

Comment: Your using it exactly as my example?  I ask because there is no function reference in that line.  the first error you get suggests that it thinks something after the `as` is a function.

Comment: @LondonDrugs_MediaServices sorry for the slow reply got busy with other things, no what you said did not work. but i manged to fix the issue with `carContainer.removeChild(carContainer.getChildByName("Car"));` so I am happy now. Thanks.

Comment: @LondonDrugs_MediaServices also just a tip that i thought might help you, add the @ tag as then you get the notification. (well the person your contacting.)

Comment: Thank you!  I've been stuck for 2 days and this post got me unstuck!

Answer (score 1):

Just use container mcs and put all your objects inside. This will act like layers.

mc1 ground depth = 100
mc2 building depth = 200
mc3 cars depth = 300
mc4 overlay (for scores) = 1000

Clips with higher depth will be above clips with lower depth. I did not choose consecutive depths like 1,2,3 so you can later add new layer between existing ones. using depth=150 for example.

To learn how to set depths for a mc use http://www.foundation-flash.com/tutorials/changingdepths/

Comment: movieClips don't have any depth properties.  Though I do agree containers are the way to go.

Comment: @LondonDrugs_MediaServices I thought you knew how to do that. You are setting depth (or z-index) when you use addChildAt(). I updated the answer with a tutorial. Make sure you master the concept of display tree and depth before continue working with flash. It's THE key concept.

Comment: you are setting a z-index of sorts with addChild, but it's only a simple index for layering.  There is no empty space between items that you can leave 'open' for later - like when using CSS for example.   The display list in flash is basically an array, and whatever order that array is in is the order in which they are layered.  You can't just do something like `mc3.z-index = 300` like with CSS.